# What is the alternative to WebSocket for Firefox (and IE)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, websocket

When looking for WebSocket on Firefox (or IE) ...

```
if ("WebSocket" in window)
{
    ...
}
else
{
    alert('Your browser does not support websocket');
}
```

They are both failing !

If they dont have any WebSocket, is there a way in JS to exchange some TCP message with a server ? (connect/send/recv ???)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) and [Faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/) for portable implementations.

Comment: I have just taken a quick look and a quick test. These solution require me to redo my server in JS ! They are also using the GET protocol. Is there a way to do simple socket from JS ? I have a server already done and running. I just need to send some command with TCP, then I want to read an answer on the same socket. Both ways doing only text.

Comment: The good thing about libraries such as these is that they abstract away incompatibilities and gracefully degrade for browsers not supporting sockets at all (such as old IEs that are in heavy use today still). Check if there are any Bayeux protocol implementations for the language you use on the server, then you can use Faye with whatever you have on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [web-socket-js](https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js) which uses Flash to add WebSockets support. In fact, Socket.IO uses web-socket-js as a fallback if the browser doesn't natively support WebSockets. Socket.IO is very nice but if you just want lower level WebSockets support without requiring your backend to be written in Javascript then there are many WebSockets servers that exist.